# Passing value from Controller to Model with relationship Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-7

I have this piece of code in my laravel project, in my controller

```
$package = Package::where('id', $req->order_package_id[$i])->with('product_package.check_member_product($this->member_code())')->first();
```

however it give and error because of my with() this cause error because I want to pass a value to my model with a code that will check the member code. but I am not sure how can I accomplished this.

```
with('product_package.check_member_product($this->member_code())')
```

which as value in check_member_product but I tried that way it is not working.

in my model

```
public function check_member_product($member_code)
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Member_stock','product_id','product_id')->where('member_id', $member_code);
    }
```

Please help... I tried auth check but i do not know why my auth check is not working on my model so I tried to pass a value from controller instead.

Comment: `with()` with a string parameter is for eager loading relationships, not running arbitrary code. Try using an array with callable instead. Check documentation for details. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: can you show your model?

Comment: @EmekaOkafor I already posted my model

Comment: @miken32 can you explain more on array callable? What I am trying to do is to pass a member which will be use to filter the result of my query in relationship. basically to foreign keys will be involved. I just need how to pass value from controller to model. as Auth is not working in Models.. :(